# What are those trx periodically being sent to the zero address

Tags: 0x

An example of such trx is the following (0x1c22498f94934e18b32f2fdb00d8bf091af7cd77e8aeea0191f21efc211aeebc) in particular they have a calldata which UTF-8 decoding looks like 'data:application/json,{"p":"ierc-20","op":"mint","tick":"sneaky","amt":"1","nonce":"1699112316166"}' which seems like a ledger for mints and transfers, but what use does it have? Those trx do not change any ethereum state nor release any events.

Comment: "Within an Ethereum transaction, the zero-account is just a special case used to indicate that a new contract is being deployed. It is literally '0x0' set to the to field in the raw transaction." (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219716/what-is-address0-in-solidity)